# Values of JSON exist in columns' JSONB array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have tricky query that attempts to find matches that compare a list of JSON arrays against a list of JSON values in a column

The "Things" table with "Keywords" column would contain something such as:

```
'["car", "house", "boat"]'::JSONB
```

The query would contain the values:

```
'["car", "house"]'::JSONB
```

I'd like to find all the rows that have BOTH "car" and "house" contained in the listing. Here's my (mostly) feeble attempt:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  "Things"
WHERE
 "Keywords"::JSONB ?| ARRAY(
     SELECT * FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS('["house","car"]'::JSONB)
  )::TEXT[]
```

Also when it comes to indexing, I'm assuming adding a GIST index would be my best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to find all the rows that have BOTH "car" and "house"

So the right operator is `?&` - [Do all of these array strings exist as top-level keys?](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

You query is almost correct, change the operator and use `jsonb_array_elements_text()`:

```
WITH "Things"("Keywords") AS (
VALUES
    ('["car", "house", "boat"]'::jsonb),
    ('["car", "boat"]'),
    ('["car", "house"]'),
    ('["house", "boat"]')
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  "Things"
WHERE
 "Keywords" ?& array(
     SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text('["house","car"]')
  )

         Keywords         
--------------------------
 ["car", "house", "boat"]
 ["car", "house"]
(2 rows)
```

The query would be simpler if the argument could be written down as a regular array of text:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  "Things"
WHERE
 "Keywords" ?& array['house', 'car']
```

In both cases you can use a [GIN index:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

> The default GIN operator class for jsonb supports queries with top-level key-exists operators ?, ?& and ?| operators (...)